# What does Disable Inspection in android studio means?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have found an error in the android studio but I have removed this error by clicking "Disable Inspection" option but I don't know its mean.

Comment: Pls Go through [How to Ask on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking first query

Answer (score 0):

An inspection is a check of your code, made by the IDE. That inspection turned up an error, which the IDE is reporting to you. If you disable the inspection, that particular check of your code will never be performed again.

Comment: Is there is any bad consequences or not to disable inspection and neglect this error..??

Comment: @RohitGurjar: Since nobody but you knows what the error is, nobody can answer that. In general, you either fix the problem or use some other option (e.g., "suppress lint") to stop the IDE from complaining for *this* specific occurrence of the problem.